# How to add function parameter after selector parameter Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, selector

I am writing a function with a definition that looks like this

```
@objc public func artOptionsTapped(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem, imageReferences: [StorageReference]?)
```

I am wondering what the proper way to call this function is if I want to pass in a list called `images` as the `imageReferences` parameter. I tried to call it like this:

```
#selector(artOptionsTapped(:_, imageReferences: images))
```

But that's causing me an error. Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible. You have to create a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want a selector to `artOptionsTapped` where the `imageReferences` parameter is always `images`. This is *partial function application*, and is not currently natively supported in Swift. To get the equivalent functionality, try this:

```swift
let images = getImages() // however you get the images
let closure = { (barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) in
    artOptionsTapped(barButtonItem, images)
}
#selector(closure(_:))
```

---

(fair warning, this may not work — I haven't tried it myself and I may not understand the context you're trying this in, but I figured it was worth a shot)